# AggregateMergeTree logic when one group by clause column is ommited

Tags: clickhouse

For example we have following table

```sql
CREATE TABLE app_events.events 
        (
        event_date Date,
        user_pseudo_id String,
        event_params_ga_session_id String,
        event_params_ga_session_number String,
        min_time AggregateFunction(min, String)
        )
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY (event_date, user_pseudo_id, 
   event_params_ga_session_id, event_params_ga_session_number  )
```

This table gets data from main table via materialized view . Main table has same structure with "timestamp" column that comes into min_time agg function column of AggregatingMergeTree table

So we can say that these queries are equal:

```
SELECT
        event_date,
        user_pseudo_id,
        event_params_ga_session_id,
        event_params_ga_session_number,
        minMerge(min_time) as min_time
FROM app_events.events
group by 
        event_date,
        user_pseudo_id,
        event_params_ga_session_id,
        event_params_ga_session_number

SELECT
        event_date,
        user_pseudo_id,
        event_params_ga_session_id,
        event_params_ga_session_number,
        min(event_timestamp) as min_time
FROM app_events.events_main 
GROUP BY 
        event_date, 
        user_pseudo_id, 
        event_params_ga_session_id, 
        event_params_ga_session_number ;
```

---

Can I say the same about following two queries ? (I only commented out first column )

```
SELECT
        --event_date, --commented out this
        user_pseudo_id,
        event_params_ga_session_id,
        event_params_ga_session_number,
        minMerge(min_time) as min_time
FROM app_events.events
group by 
        --event_date, --commented out this
        user_pseudo_id,
        event_params_ga_session_id,
        event_params_ga_session_number

SELECT
        --event_date,--commented out this
        user_pseudo_id,
        event_params_ga_session_id,
        event_params_ga_session_number,
        min(event_timestamp) as min_time
FROM app_events.events_main
where 
GROUP BY 
--event_date, --commented out this
user_pseudo_id, 
event_params_ga_session_id, 
event_params_ga_session_number ;
```

Will AggregateMergeTree choose right state ? We have no order in AggregateMergeTree without event_date so question is will query with Merge and without event_date column  select latest state of aggregation  based on event_timestamp even event_date is ommited in group by clause ?

Comment: Can you fix the formatting? It's kind of hard to follow...

Answer (score 0):

> Will AggregateMergeTree choose right state ?

It will.

It works not the way you think. It's irrelevant that a table has an AggregatingMergeTree engine.

All *MergeTree engines are processed by the SELECT the same agnonistically to the engine. minMerge is a an aggregate function, it aggregates the input values no matter which group by is used using usual agg/groupby. It will not jump to the right row, no it will process all rows and it will find the right value using aggregation.

Comment: Thank you 
One little question , im just not sure completely , should I use some specific sharding key in case of using AggregatingMergeTree in clustered clickhouse , I mean is it allowed to have two rows with same GROUP BY combination on diffenerent nodes ( It can be so if I use rand() sharding.)

Comment: Usually a sharding is the same as a base table sharding, because AggregatingMergeTree is used with a Materialized View and Materialized View is attached to a *MergeTree table not a Distributed. It's very rare that you need to use Distributed table as a source for a Materialized view.